# Почему селектор :selected возвращает неверный результат?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть форма поиска, в ней select2 дропдаун, селектор стран. Дефолтное значение - Тайланд. В форме выбираю Турцию, перехожу в поиск - все чудесно работает (переход на ту же страницу, но с выбранной страной). Далее жму на back в браузере и получаю вот такой интересный результат
http://prntscr.com/7x0jw6

```
// Консолим элемент до того как он будет изменен плагином
console.log($countrySelect[0]); // Вот тут у нас видно, выбран Тайланд
console.log($(':selected', $countrySelect)[0]); // А вот тут, что Турция

$countrySelect.select2({
    width: "style",
    theme: "classic",
    language: "ru",
    widthFix: 1,
    templateResult: function (state) {
        if (!state.id) {
            return state.text;
        }

        return $("<div class='flag flag-spr flag-" + state.element.value + "'></div><span class='country-name'>" + state.text + "</span>");
    },
    templateSelection: function (state) {
        return $("<div class='flag flag-spr flag-" + state.element.value + "'></div><span class='country-name'>" + state.text + "</span>");
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(m) {
        return m;
    }
});
```

Как так?

Comment: Так и не понял, что не так то? То что Тайланд по умолчанию? Так и должно быть. Вы же сами сказали, что нажали кнопку back

Comment: Он должен быть по умолчанию. Я приложил скрин после кнопки бек, и в приведенном коде видно что именно я консолил. Вам не кажется странным, что в элементе селектед тайланд, а селектор по :selected возвращает Турцию?